# Parsing using regex in recursive functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, recursion

I want to parse a string which contains shortcodes and push each extracted node into an array. However the recursive function I have written for this never terminates. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var i = 0;
var nodes = [];
var pattern = /(\[sc_(\w+)[\s\w="_-]*\])(.*)(\[\/sc_\2\])/gi;

var extractNodes = function(str, parent) {
    var m;

    if (str.indexOf('[sc_') === -1) return;

    while ((m = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {
        nodes.push({
            id: i,
            tag: m[2],
            children: m[3],
            parentId: parent
        });
        extractNodes(m[3], i++);
    }
}

extractNodes("[sc_div][sc_span][sc_strong]Foo[/sc_strong][/sc_span][/sc_div]", -1);
```

Comment: can you tell us what the output would be for your example here?

Comment: Missed `return` in the recursive function. [`return extractNodes(m[3], i++);`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/p4jkkado/)

Comment: @Tushar return doesn't seem to be the issue.  There is something about the regex, its sending the same `str` parameter for every iteration:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/9yaz6cdu/

Comment: @AdamKonieska Right! The code is missing [`break`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36393687/2025923)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a conflict between your while loop and the global (*`g` flag*) RegEx.

Each iteration of the function is sending the same `str` parameter. You can fix this by making the RegEx non-global by removing the `g` flag and `while` loop.

[**Live Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/9yaz6cdu/1/)

```js
var i = 0;
var nodes = [];
var pattern = /(\[sc_(\w+)[\s\w="_-]*\])(.*)(\[\/sc_\2\])/i; // <-- Remove `g` flag

var extractNodes = function (str, parent) {
    var m;
    if (str.indexOf('[sc_') === -1) return;

    if ((m = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {
        nodes.push({
            id: i,
            tag: m[2],
            children: m[3],
            parentId: parent
        });

        extractNodes(m[3], i++);
    }
}

extractNodes("[sc_div][sc_span][sc_strong]Foo[/sc_strong][/sc_span][/sc_div]", -1);
console.log(nodes);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(nodes, 0, 4) + '</pre>'; // For DEMO purpose only
```

**Console Output (Chrome):**

> [Object, Object, Object]
>   0:Object
>     children: "[sc_span][sc_strong]Foo[/sc_strong][/sc_span]"
>     id: 0
>     parentId: -1
>     tag: "div"
>     __proto__: Object
>   1:Object
>     children: "[sc_strong]Foo[/sc_strong]"
>     id: 1
>     parentId: 0
>     tag: "span"
>     __proto__: Object
>   2:Object
>     children: "Foo"
>     id: 2
>     parentId: 1
>     tag: "strong"
>     __proto__: Object
>   length: 3
>   __proto__: Array[0]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this won't work when there are siblings. Imagine the following input:
```[sc_div][sc_span][sc_strong]Foo[/sc_strong][/sc_span][/sc_div]
[sc_div][sc_span][sc_strong]Bar[/sc_strong][/sc_span][/sc_div]```

Comment: @coder9 Make the regex `non-greedy` by using `?` `(\[sc_(\w+)[\s\w="_-]*\])(.*?)(\[\/sc_\2\])`